# Google font not loading on mobile

Tags: mobile, media-queries, github-pages, google-fonts

Just recently launched a website using github pages, and everything works great except ONE of the two typefaces I'm using doesn't load on mobile. It works if you resize a desktop browser to mobile size, so it shouldn't be an issue with the media queries. Is this just a problem on Google's side? it doesn't work on any of the browser apps I have on my phone. website is live here: [bamfbham.com](http://bamfbham.com)

Comment: Which font and can you give an example location?

Comment: "titillium web", it's the heading font for all of the content pages. http://bamfbham.com/getinvolved.html

Comment: roboto and roboto mono both work fine, and I did previously have them all in one embed code but took Titillium Web into its own code to see if that would fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using import instead.

```
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web');
</style>
```